# Landing page redirects

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, pagespeed

Recently, I did a speed test on my website and discovered that I had too many landing page redirects on the website and it was slowing the site down.

I've seen that I need to update the `.htacess` file with this code.

`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

I'm not sure whtether the code is specefic to a certain site or can be used on any.

If I update the `.htacess` document with the code above will this fix my problem?

Comment: first remove this RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]. then this code is to force website into https , so from http to https

Comment: Will I need to remove any code in the .htacess document before adding this?

Comment: it depends in what you want to do

Comment: I'm trying to avoid landing page redirects, to increase page load speed.

Comment: this is another issue , the code above will only force http to https but if you have another issue , paste ur .htaccess to let us see what inside it